# Why does the ++ operator increase an integer by 4 and not by 1?

Tags: objective-c, c

I've got some simple code in Objective-C wich consist of a button and a label. When you click the button once, the labels shows: "u hit me", if you click it twice, the message will be: "i did it again". But, if u hit the button 5x or more, the message should be: "STOP THAT";

I used simple `if`s and a counter that is increased using the operator `++`. The problem is: My counter increases in steps of 4, and not in steps of one.

Here's the code

```
@implementation hitMe

NSString *myString = @"";
int *counter = 0;

- (IBAction)htM:(id)sender {
    if ([myString isEqualToString:@""]){
        //first hit
        myString = @"u hit me";
    } else {  
    //  second and next hits...
        myString = @"u did it again!";
        counter++;
    }

    // if I use "counter > 5" it doesn't work,
    // I have to use 21 if I want the button hit 5 times before
    // I get the "STOP THAT" message

    if (counter > 21) {
        myString = @"STOP THAT ";
    } 

    [labelOne setStringValue:myString];

    // I used this only to check the count value
    [labelTwo setIntValue:counter];
}

@end
```

Comment: You're experienced in *what* languages exactly? Given that the `++` operator is a C-ism, not an Objective-C-ism, I'm guessing it's not anything from the C/C++ family tree.

Comment: Also, some Objective-C tips: Class names are camel-case by convention. Method names are usually quite descriptive, one doesn't use shortened method or variable names like *htM* instead of *hitMe*. We also don't care about your level of experience, all programmers are welcome on stackoverflow regardless if they are beginners or experts. :)

Comment: sorry if I offended U with my english ! that's not my native language, unfortanelly I have to use it as a learning tool...
I believe, that was not the point here .... 
And just to U know, I know very well how to name my functions, but, when Im doing a "hitme" test program, only to learn the synthax of obj-c, I do not have to name very well the TWO functions I have... PS: the other function was before called as "hitMe" ....

Comment: it's important to tailor your English for the audience; here are some tips for StackOverflow and other professional interactions: (1) Don't use txt-spelling. You have a keyboard. Use it. (Misspelled words because you can't figure out how to get the right spelling from a dictionary is one thing, but `u` or `2` instead of `you` or `to` shows disrespect.) (2) Simple punctuation: end sentences with a single `.` or `?`, and one space after the punctuation. (3) Capitalize `I`, and first word of every sentence. No one expects perfection, but these idioms are simple and show respect. :)

Comment: If English is not your native language, you should be very upset at whoever taught you that `U` is an acceptable replacement for the word `you`. It's not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The variable you're incrementing, `counter`, is a pointer to an int, not an int.  So the compiler turns:

```
counter++;
```

into

```
counter += 4; // sizeof(int) == 4
```

which is what is needed to get to the next word in memory, or the next location you might point to. This might seem weird, but if you had an array of ints and a pointer that you were using to examine them, incrementing the pointer would take you to the next int (which is four bytes on most architectures these days).

Change `int *counter` to `int counter` and you should be fine.

---

Edit: The C language spec defines pointer arithmetic (what happens when you add or subtract with pointers) this way because the most common use of pointer math is to navigate around an array that you're pointing to.  So one unit of increment for a pointer is one unit of the array, or `sizeof(arrayType)`.  A char* would have given you the behavior you expected, because `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: @Diego Favero: `why does it happens?` Because a 64 bit int is 4 bytes. If `int *x` points to a mem location, incrementing x is incrementing a pointer to a 64 bits int. Hence +4 bytes.

Comment: Hi Seamus Campbell ! thns soo much, it has been working very well ! but now, I gotta other quest: why does it happens? : 
" So the compiler turns: counter++; into counter += 4; "
because I also tried " counter = counter + 1 " and got the same result

Comment: See my edit above.  It's just the way pointer math works in C.  It's all addition, not just ++.