# Why can't I increment the variable one by one?

Tags: objective-c

Whenever I click the button `flipButton` once, the variable `curPage` added 4. I want to increment it by one. Could someone tell me what is wrong? 
Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    curPage = 0 ;
    NSString * dic = nil;
    if ((NSInteger)tempIndex == 0) {
        type = @"Fire_";
        dic = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",type,0];
    }
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dic ofType:@"htm"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [contentWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Flip"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(flipView)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
}

-(IBAction)flipView{
    curPage = curPage + 1;
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",type,(int)curPage];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@"htm"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [contentWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    NSLog(path);
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of curPage? I see you cast it to an int. You should not have to do that.

Comment: Also, try placing `NSLog(@"%@",curPage);` after
`curPage = curPage + 1;`

Comment: Should the flipView function be of the type IBAction ? I thought IBAction was designed for storyboards. But, in the above code, you are associating flipView with a button which you created programmatically

Comment: I was using int *curPage;
After I changed it into  int curPage; What's the difference?

Comment: @IsaiahTurner don't use `@"%@"` but `@"%d"`. `int` is a scalar value, not an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the ++ operator increase an integer by 4 and not by 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521700/why-does-the-operator-increase-an-integer-by-4-and-not-by-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this is because you put an asterisk after an `int` when declaring `curPage`:

```
int *curPage;
```

That's also the reason why the compiler insisted on you adding `(int)` in front of `curPage` when passing it to `stringWithFormat:`

This declares an integer pointer, not an integer. Pointers increment by the size of whatever they point to, so on platforms with 32-bit `int`s they increment by four (the number of bytes taken by 32 bits). You do not need asterisks when declaring variables of primitive types.